# If a, b, c are positive numbers then prove that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a}\geq a+b+c$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials

> If a, b, c are positive numbers then prove that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a}\geq a+b+c$.

I tried using AM-GM inequality, $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ $$a^2+b^2+2ab\geq 4ab$$ $$ a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$$
Dividing both sides by $a+b$, $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}$$
Similarly, $$\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}\geq \frac{2bc}{b+c}$$ $$\frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a}\geq \frac{2ca}{c+a}$$
Adding all, we get, $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a}\geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}+\frac{2bc}{b+c}+\frac{2ca}{c+a}$$
Now, I have no idea what to do. Can we simplify RHS to get $a+b+c$ or is there a different method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b} \ge a+b+c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424150/prove-that-fracb2c2bc-fracc2a2ca-fraca2b2ab-ge-ab). Note I found this using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E2%2Bb%5E2%7D%7Ba%2Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%7D%7Bb%2Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%5E2%2Ba%5E2%7D%7Bc%2Ba%7D%5Cgeq%20a%2Bb%2Bc%24&p=1), with it also showing an AoPS thread of [Basic Inequality 4](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1198291p5878790).

Comment: Yes, that does answer it.

Comment: Here's an approach using just AM-GM that you started with: Show that $a^2/(a+b) + (a+b) / 2 \geq 2a$. Then sum up the 6 inequalities. $\quad$ The idea is that you generally want terms that already exist, so it's a question of how to manipulate them. Whereas introducing $2ab/(a+b)$ doesnt' seem to lead us anywhere further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use $\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x+y} \ge \dfrac{x+y}{2}$.

Comment: How do you get this statement?

Comment: Just adding, to derive that result use $a^2+b^2≥2ab$ and just add $a^2+b^2$ to both sides and re-arrange

Comment: Oh thanks, that solves it nicely.